# Intersection test for all records in a postgis table for each other

Tags: postgis, intersection, 3d

I have a table "spheres". I want to check if there are any intersections between the records of these table in 3D. I want to use ST_3D Intersection. But I don't know how I can make using this function for intersection test between every geometry records in a single table. In examples intersections are made two between different tables and geometries. I want to make intersection tests between different geometries but they are in the same table. How can this be done??

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please  [edit] the question to contain your best effort at the SQL to perform this self-join query.  You **must** include code in coding questions before we can help you, you should also indicate any errors or unwanted behavior. You might only be able to get to 2D overlap with SQL.